# Run time analysis for the following few cases?

Tags: algorithm

I'm ranking the following from slowest growth to fastest growth:

```
a) 2^log(n)
b) 2^2^log(n)
c) n^5/2
d) 2^n^2
e) n^2*log(n)
```

I have `a < b < e < c < d` but I was told that's wrong. Can someone provide a helpful answer and explanation? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) is exponential, since exponentiation is right-associative. That is, 2^2^log(n) is equal to 2^(2^log(n)) = 2^n, not 4^log(n). The relative order of the other 4 is correct; you just need to bump b up to a higher position (which position I leave to you to figure out).